# Is there a free (LGPL, BSD, etc) implementation of XML editor swing component

Tags: java, swing

I need a JComponent thad enables editing xml documents so I can embed it in my application.

It doesnt need to bee fancy.

Plain text editing and highlighting would bee enough.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this [Xml Editor](http://darwin-it.blogspot.com/2008/09/java-swing-xml-editor-and-tester.html) would do:

> I had to enhance and restructure my XML Editor to make it a "plugable" JPanel.

Otherwise, you still have the [SimpleEditor.java](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/_distrib/doc/dev/embed1.html) which might be as good.

[image]
<sub>(source: [xmlmind.com](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/_distrib/doc/dev/resources/SimpleEditor.png))</sub>